# How do you execute a ./executable in Python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have an executable that is a result of compiling and running a C program.

Let's Call it "file1".

Normally, this is how I'd execute it in Linux.

```
./file1
```

But now, I need to execute it from within Python.

I've tried

```
os.system("./file1")
```

-to no avail. Can someone please help me out?

P.S - Apologies for the bizzare spacing.

Comment: using subprocess is better. However os.system should also work. If it doesn't maybe there is a problem with the path. I think that os.system will use the directory where the python executable is, as its working directory.

Comment: By "to no avail" do you mean: it raises an exception, returns an error code, exits silently?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini There Was a problem with the path Emanuele :) I read this comment after figuring that out

Comment: @bereal It returned an error, but to be fair, the error was mine :) Thanks bereal

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini What I'd done was, switch to the directory of the executable using a cd command in the os.system call and proceeded to run the executable in the next call. But the previous command hadn't switched to the executable's directory at all. Silly me :D

Comment: @abhiii5459 if you execute two commands in different os.system calls, each commands starts a new shell. So changing the working directory on the first command does not affect the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['./file1'])
```

Comment: Thanks :) This worked  :) ALthough, I fixed my os.system error as well :)